# How can I type this (number, hebrew, number) on Stack Exchange sites, aligned left?

Tags: discussion, bug

I'm not 100% sure if this is suitable for meta but anyhow.

In [Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word), I can type this as shown in the image.

Note - the letter is the Hebrew letter aleph (UTF-16 code of 05D0). It can be copy/pasted from charmap.

[image]

On a Stack Exchange site, I can type

aaa,אאא,bbb

and have it aligned left.

But I can't see how to type the other line. It keeps ending up looking like 1,אאא,2

Even if I type 1 then, then אאא, and then 2, it ends up as 1, then 2, and then אאא.

Interestingly, if I type 1, then 2, and then אאא it also ends up in that order, 1, then 2, and then אאא.

Hebrew is a right-to-left language...

It seems that the Stack Exchange site is counting the number and the comma as Hebrew... And thus it won't do it; it won't put the comma after the Hebrew, whereas a word seems to count comma as English, and so lets me.

And that's even when/though I'm using the English keyboard to type comma.

I've tagged it bug, but I don't know if one would call it a bug... [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) has the same issue... Word is fine... But it seems strange that whether I type the keys 1,aleph,aleph,aleph,2 or I type 1,2,aleph,aleph,aleph, the text comes up the same order,  1,2,aleph,aleph,aleph. That, and that I can't get 1,aleph,aleph,aleph,2 to appear in that order.

Comment: No bug, support for RTL layout/languages simply does not exist, at the moment.